# Port Forwarding Based on Hostname in Windows Server

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

I have Server A host a Website A and I have Server B host a Website B. They are both in Port 80 and using IIS in Windows Server 2016.

I have different domain for both server and both website said [www.websiteA.com](http://www.websiteA.com) and [www.websiteB.com](http://www.websiteB.com)

I just have 1 public IP and in my router DMZ Server set to Server A.

How to make if I access [www.websiteA.com](http://www.websiteA.com) it will access server A and if I access [www.websiteB.com](http://www.websiteB.com), it will access server B?

I know it can be done with proxy server. My current router doesn't support that. But is it possible to do that just with port forwarding or something like that in Windows Server?

I have tried making another IIS as HTTP Redirect but it just redirecting it to server B with it's IP not something like Port Forwarding.

Comment: for most routers, D-NAT/port-forwarding only allows one internal system per port per IP. to do what you want, you will need any of the following; multiple public IPs, different ports, a load balancer, or a proxy. support for multiple public IPs will require an enterprise-grade router.

Comment: *"I know it can be done with proxy server. My current router doesn't support that."* - You may wish to explain what you mean by this.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it works using Reverse Proxy 3.0 in Web Platform Installer

1. Install URL Rewriter
2. Install Reverse Proxy
3. Make a new site using [www.websiteA.com](http://www.websiteA.com) as hostname
4. Make another B site using [www.websiteB.com](http://www.websiteB.com) as hostname
5. Click the B site and find URL Rewrite in right window
6. In URL Rewrite add Rule and choose Reverse Proxy
7. Fill the inbound rule to your local IP server. For example 192.168.1.2

Done!